# Customising top of DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout

Maybe some kind of simple question to those who are skilled at android layouts, but what is the best approach to draw smth like this (maybe what widget to use) for positioning rounded area which spreads out of top border of dialogFragment and is horizontally  centered like this:[image]

Comment: My Suggestion is take image with that cut out

Comment: The simplest way is using a round image

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom layout for Dialogs.
In this case, you have all the control you want for defining dialogs layout, same as for any view.

If heart icon is all you have, create an xml for white circle and use it as a background for the heart, set it to top of parent, center it horizontally.
As you will have exact height of circle, you can set half of it as top margin for the rest of the layout below to make circle look like a hump (as on screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 9 patch as the background of you dialog. Define the stretch areas and the content area and you should be good :

[image]

And for exemple use this 9 patch file:

[image]